# How to build reverse mapping URLs inside JSP using spring mvc router?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using spring-mvc-router to have all URLs in a centralized location. How can I make reverse mapping of my controllers inside JSP files?

Comment: please elaborate your question...

Answer (score 0):

It's very well described in the readme page of the project, section [integrating with JSP](https://github.com/resthub/springmvc-router#integrating-with-jsp):

In your JSP, declare the taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="route" uri="/springmvc-router" %>
```

Then use the reverse method to generate URLs:

```
<a href="<route:reverse action="userController.listAll" />">List all users</a>
```

Dynamic parameters can also be used:

```
<a href="<route:reverse action="userController.showUser"
   userId="42" />">Show user 42</a>
```